# MySQL - Return Incorrect UTF8 characters

Tags: c#, mysql, utf-8

my codes return incorrect UTF8 characters. I'm not sure how to fix it.

I create my table by using this code:

```
string sql = @"
CREATE TABLE `งปลา` (
`วงปลา` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`ทศไท` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`วงปลา`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
";

using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(txtConstring.Text))
{
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        conn.Open();

        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

and I insert some sample data like this:

```
string sql = "";
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(txtConstring.Text))
{
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        conn.Open();

        sql = "insert into `งปลา`(`ทศไท`)values('งปลาทศไท');"; ;
        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

now, if I execute this:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(txtConstring.Text))
{
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        conn.Open();

        cmd.CommandText = "show create table `งปลา`;";
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);

        conn.Close();
    }
}

dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

It return this:

```
CREATE TABLE `????` (
  `?????` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `????` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`?????`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

And this:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(txtConstring.Text))
{
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        conn.Open();

        cmd.CommandText = "select * from `งปลา`;";
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);

        conn.Close();
    }
}

dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

will return this table:

```
--------------------
| ????? | ????     |
--------------------
| 1     | ???????? |
| 2     | ???????? |
| 3     | ???????? |
--------------------
```

All the Thai characters are not showing properly.

This are the MySQL server chatacter set:

```
show variables like 'character%';

Variable_name              Value 
-------------              -----------
character_set_client       latin1 
character_set_connection   latin1 
character_set_database     latin1 
character_set_server       latin1 
character_set_system       utf8
```

I know that the default character set should be UTF8, however, I don't have the privilege to change the default character set.

This is the sample project that I have created >> [TestThaiMySQL_Test2.zip](http://www.mediafire.com/download/esz0168o18jay35) 
it will generate the error.
A sample database is created.
 The connection string is coded together inside the sample project.

So, the question is, how to return the Thai characters correctly?

Any idea? hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things need to be done to get this to work:

Change the charset of the connection itself: in the connection string use `charset=utf8`

Make sure the database and table charsets are set correctly. See here for setting the database charset: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-database.html

(It's unclear, but my understanding is that these charset options need to be set before creating the table in question.)

Comment: According to: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connection-options.html , charset in connection string is used to define the character set of queries that sent to MySQL, it does not affect the returning result set. And I have tested it too. The MySQL server does not recognize the Thai character in the SQL query after setting charset=utf8 in connection string.

Comment: Can you check through another tool that the table was created correctly originally? If it were created without the correct charset being set the name could be corrupted. Try recreating with `charset=utf8`. Another option is per the MySQL docs at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html and using `SET NAMES 'utf8'` to set all the charset options.

Comment: It seems to appear the same.

Comment: Hi @Osborn, it works if the database is created with UTF8. If it is not, modify the database default charset to UTF8 will solve the problem too. Thanks for the help. You may update your answer so that I can have a vote for this answer.

Comment: @mjb I've updated my comment to include your solution. Good to hear you were able to solve this.